# Permission Denied

Tags: ros, ros-electric, permission, permissions, nxt-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on Ubuntu 10.04 and I have ROS Electric installed.
I am following these instructions and I am on Step 3 (Generating the URDF): http://wiki.ros.org/nxt_lxf2urdf/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20simple%20robot%20model%20using%20lxf2urdf.py#Renaming_and_Positioning_Links

When I input the command `rosrun nxt_lxf2urdf lxf2urdf.py robot.lxf robot.ldr >robot.urdf` I get:

```
[rospack] WARNING: cannot create rospack cache directory: Permission denied
[rospack] WARNING: cannot create rospack cache directory: Permission denied
[rospack] Unable to create temporary cache file /root/.ros/.rospack_cache.cSxwgs: Permission denied
```

What to do? I am fairly new to Ubuntu and ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206727/permission-denied/) by [Joelac0193](https://answers.ros.org/users/22079/joelac0193/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-04-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-07**:
The error seems to suggest you once ran things as the `root` user ("[..] file /root/.ros/.."). Can you think of a reason why that would be the case? Your normal user does not have access to that directory, but a typical ROS installation wouldn't need a dir in `/root/` either.

**Comment by [Joelac0193](https://answers.ros.org/users/22079/joelac0193/) on 2015-04-07**:
Well whenever I do anything in the terminal I always input this command: sudo -i

**Comment by [Joelac0193](https://answers.ros.org/users/22079/joelac0193/) on 2015-04-07**:
Nevermind I got it. I input the command sudo -s and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Well whenever I do anything in the terminal I always input this command: sudo -i

Why do you use `sudo`? A normal ROS installation shouldn't need it?

If you need it to access (serial) devices, please see [Rosrun as super user](http://answers.ros.org/question/189457/rosrun-as-super-user/#189462).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gkbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/33705/gkbot/) on 2018-02-14**:
I have the same issue. I believe the problem is due to having a different partition for /home during installation of ubuntu.
sudo gives the right permissions to make any file edits. There should be a work around, but I have not yet figured it out. Any ideas?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Your own user should be able to access its own files. If not, that is a system configuration issue, and should be fixed. That would seem to be something not related to ROS, so I would suggest asking it over at Ask Ubuntu or a similar forum.

**Comment by [DavidGuitarMetal](https://answers.ros.org/users/27894/davidguitarmetal/) on 2018-05-08**:
You can try `rosdep fix-permissions` as a workaround, it worked for me